# Will the Apple Store replace Macbook Pro keys or other parts if serious wearing occurs?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, repair

I have had my first MacBook for around a month now and I'm already beginning to notice some wearing on the keys (especially on the spacebar). The keys are beginning to turn shiny, and at this rate they might be completely eroded in six months. I have tried cleaning them with a dry cloth (I have yet to try with a wet cloth) but it seems that it is indeed physical wearing and not just a spot of grease.

I think I have read on another forum that if you bring your MacBook to an Apple Store and ask for replacement they'll remove your keys and replace them with new ones. **Is this true? Do they charge for it?**

I don't mean to sound whiny. I am asking this question because my MacBook cost me quite a lot and its exterior aspect is an important part of the experience: seeing parts of the keyboard starting to wear is somewhat frustrating.

Comment: Are you sure the keys are wearing out? My keys get shiny from use but if I clean the keyboard (wet cloth) they return to the way they looked before. I think a piece of the shinyness may be oil from your hands, not wear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than ask us, you might ask your local store since they are the ones that will make the call.

My guess is if you have a functional problem where you loved the Mac to death and used it so much the keys are worn, they would replace it under AppleCare or the standard Warranty. I wouldn't expect warranty service for normal wear and tear and this will likely be up to them to make the call whether your specific instance is one or the other.

Also - do go in if you are frustrated with your purchase. Go now and not later, since the sooner you show them wearing, the sooner they can document it and it's more likely they'll want to replace something that is wearing out prematurely. Think like tires, if yours wear out in under 5000 miles (or km) it's clearly something the warranty should cover. Several years of wear isn't a defect in the manufacturing and just plain old you wore it out.